# Fixed table headers to dynamic table

Tags: css, angularjs, html, html-table, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a quite dynamic table where you can hide and show different columns (and also change the order on the columns).

I've tried a few directives and plugins but no one is working well (or as I expect...I am doing wrong) for me.

Can you guys help me to get the table header fixed?

[plnkur](http://plnkr.co/edit/I3u8DkS0I3O4DM0X18ki?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/slate/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div ng:controller="MainCtrl">

<p>Visible Columns:</p>
<div class="cbxList" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.checked">{{column.id}}
</div>
<br/>

<table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
  <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="column.id"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="row[column.id]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.columnsTest = [{
    id: 'Value1',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 'Value2',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 'Value3',
    checked: true
  }];


  $scope.columnToggled = function(column) {
    $('[data-col-id="' + column.id + '"]').each(function() {
      var element = this;
      if ($(element).hasClass('ng-hide')) {
        $(element).removeClass('ng-hide');
      } else {
        $(element).addClass('ng-hide');
      }
    });
  };


  $scope.rows = [{
    id: 1,
    "Value1": 911,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }, {
    id: 2,
    "Value1": 200,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }]; //and so on..
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What visual effect are you looking for? (Can adding CSS to thead help you?)

Comment: I would like the headers to be fixed when scrolling down the table

Comment: See related question 'HTML table with fixed headers'

Comment: They didn't work so well with my dynamic table